# Import Qt resources when are main.cpp and GUI classes in dependend static lib project,

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2005, linker

**Scenario:**

I have MSVC2005 with the Qt Visual Studio AddIn installed. In my solution there is a project **A** consisting of multiple plain C++ code modules, which is built to an executable `A.exe`. Project **A** does not contain a `.cpp` file with a `main()`, but has a dependency on a project **B**.

**B** is a Qt project built as a static lib. It consists on multiple GUI classes an a Qt-typical main.cpp(). Compiling an linking **A** and **B** works like a charm and I have a Qt-application. I made some forks of **A** (**Afork1**, **Afork2**, etc.) that all share the same interface to the GUI but have different customizations of the underlying business logic. I can batch build `A.exe`, `Afork1.exe`, ..., etc. and they all will have the same GUI, which is pretty neat.

**Problem:**

In **B** there is a `.qrc` file with multiple images, icons, etc. that are used in the GUI. The GUI classes are crafted with Qt Designer and I added the ressources to the GUI widgets. After building and running `A.exe` I cannot see these icons and images, the space for them is reserved in the widgets but not filled with the content. I guess, the ressources are not linked into the executable. Is there a way to ensure the linking of ressources that are part of Qt static lib project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the resources explicitly. From the [Qt docs](http://qt.nokia.com/doc/4.0/resources.html):

> If you have resources in a static
>   library, you might need to force
>   initialization of your resources by
>   calling Q_INIT_RESOURCE() with the
>   base name of the .qrc file. For
>   example:
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     QApplication app(argc, argv);
>     Q_INIT_RESOURCE(graphlib);
>     ...
>     return app.exec();
> }
> ```